# Creating a Event with Google Meet link in Google calendar - Event is creating but there is error in creating meet

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api, google-meet

*Hi,*
I am trying to create a google meet link in a google event through .net application,

Token generating and event creating part works well but meet creating part shows the error,
Here is required code,

In Controller,

```
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                var id = (string)jsonObject["id"];
                var createdEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Event>(response.Content);
                //string meetingLink = createdEvent.ConferenceData.EntryPoints[0].Uri;
                // Create a conference for the event
                var conferenceRequest = new CreateConferenceRequest();
                //pass RequestId
                var Id = conferenceRequest.RequestId;
                var conferenceModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(conferenceRequest, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
                });

                var conferenceRequestUrl = $"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/{id}/createConference";
                var conferenceRequestRestClient = new RestClient(conferenceRequestUrl);
                var conferenceRequestRestRequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                conferenceRequestRestRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokens["access_token"]);
                conferenceRequestRestRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                conferenceRequestRestRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conferenceRequestRestRequest.AddParameter("application/json", conferenceModel, ParameterType.RequestBody);

                var conferenceRequestResponse = conferenceRequestRestClient.Execute(conferenceRequestRestRequest);
                if (conferenceRequestResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    var conferenceResponseContent = JObject.Parse(conferenceRequestResponse.Content);
                    var conferenceData = conferenceResponseContent["conferenceData"];
                    var meetLink = conferenceData?["entryPoints"]?.FirstOrDefault(x => x["entryPointType"].ToString() == "video")?["uri"]?.ToString();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(meetLink))
                    {
                        // Do something with the meetLink (e.g., store it, display it, etc.)
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { status = "Success" });
                }

            }
```

```
In model
public class CreateConferenceRequest
        {
            public CreateConferenceRequest()
            {
                RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); // Generate a unique request ID
                ConferenceSolutionKey Cf = new ConferenceSolutionKey();
                {
                    Cf.Type = "hangoutsMeet"; // Use Google Meet as the conference solution
                };
            }

            public string RequestId { get; set; }



            public class ConferenceSolutionKey
            {
                public string Type { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

Error occured in *var conferenceRequestUrl = $"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/{id}/createConference";*

If anyone have idea or resources related to this question please share it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's probably why you're getting the error: **Id** should be **id**

````
    var id = conferenceRequest.RequestId; // Id should be id
    var conferenceRequestUrl = $"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/{id}/createConference";```
````